# Add filters to api request in Symfony 6

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine, symfony6

some time ago I saw one symfony project that allows frontend to make filtered api requests using a syntax I like: `property[operator]=value` for example `date[gte]=value` etc..
I'm sure they don't use api platform in the project but I don't understand how can I do that.

Is there any library that do the jobs?
Thanks

Comment: I don't konw if is there a lib for that but there are a lot of ways to do it in symfony, what is your main problem, how did you coded the api's backend if you don't use API Platform?

Comment: You can build api without using api platform, create a controller, mark with the Route attribute call your repository to get data and you've done a simple api.
Of course you need to implement manual pagination, sorting and filters if you need.
My problem is that I don't know how to achieve that filter syntax and how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

I´m not sure on which part you encounter any problems or how you tried to solve your problem, but you can easily build this. I made some pseudo controller code showing one way how you could do it.

```
public function api(Request $request, EntityManagerInterface $em): Response
{

    // Restrict fields and operators
    $allowed_fields = ['field_1', 'field_2'];
    $allowed_operators = ['gt', 'lt'];
    $found_filters = [];

    // Go through the query and look for valid filters
    foreach ($request->query->all() as $fieldname => $filters) {
        if (in_array($fieldname, $allowed_fields) && is_array($filters)) {
            foreach ($filters as $operator => $value) {
                $found_filters[$fieldname] = [$operator => $value];
            }
        }
    }

    // Example filtering using doctrine queryBuilder
    $qb = $em->createQueryBuilder();
    $qb->select('u')->from('User', 'u')->where('u.status = active');

    foreach ($found_filters as $fieldname => $filter) {
        foreach ($filter as $operator => $value) {
            switch ($operator) {
                case 'gt':
                    $qb->andWhere($qb->expr()->gt('u.' . $fieldname, ':' . $fieldname . "-" . $operator));
                    break;

                case 'lt':
                    $qb->andWhere($qb->expr()->lt('u.' . $fieldname, ':' . $fieldname . "-" . $operator));
                    break;

            }
            $qb->setParameter($fieldname . "-" . $operator, $value);
        }
    }

    $query = $qb->getQuery();
    $result = $query->getResult();
}
```

I guess you can easily extend this to your needs. The most importand thing IMHO is to make sure you can not make malicious or erronous queries here, this is why im using prepared statements and a whitelist of operators and filters, sure you want to add some validation on top, hope it helps

Referrence: https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.17/reference/query-builder.html#d355222ea2bf3af2880c1a9199a32eeac3db714f

Comment: thanks @john-smith this could work.
I'm not sure if that they do like that, because in the project I saw they have the this syntax also on the parameter section of api documentation, so I'm wondering if they use some library to abstract this behavior on each endpoint that returns filtered response.

Comment: Well i guess the only way to find that out is to ask the maintainers, but the fact that it appears in their documentation says nothing about how they do implemented it. If you would annotate my example code accordingly you could also automatically generate a documentation from it. anyway i just wanted to show how easy it is